# Multiple $match in PHP Mongo Aggregate

Tags: php, mongodb

Im having issues using $match twice in a Mongo Aggregate query. As the query is entered into an array it appears to be overwriting the first $match with the second $match, and therefore not querying properly. Is there a way to query with two matches?

```
$aggArray = array(array(
'$match'=>array('payload.location.coordinates.0'=>array('$gte'=>$longmin,'$lte'=>$longmax),'payload.location.coordinates.1'=>array('$gte'=>$latmin,'$lte'=>$latmax),'time'=>array('$gte'=>new MongoDate($time1),'$lte'=>new MongoDate($time2))),
'$project'=>array('payload.location.coordinates'=>1,'time'=>array('$hour'=>'$time')),
'$match'=>array('time'=>array('$gte'=>10,'$lte'=>12))
));
```

My current query in Mongo is:

```
db.getCollection('datas').aggregate(
{"$match":{"payload.location.coordinates.0":{"$gte":-0.489,"$lte":0.236},"payload.location.coordinates.1":{"$gte":51.28,"$lte":51.686},"time":{"$gte":new Date(2016,0,10),"$lte":new Date(2016,0,12)}}},
{"$project":{"payload.location.coordinates":1,"time":{"$hour":"$time"}}},
{"$match":{"time":{"$gte":10,"$lte":12}}})
```

This takes a set of data, queries within a certain geo-bounding box (`payload.location.coordinates`) over a time period (in this case Jan 10th to Jan 12th). It then projects the hour of each record, before querying for records within a given hour range over those dates (`time:{"$gte":10,"$lte":12}`). The output is a set of results from the original data series, returning `time` (as an hour) and `payload.location.coordinates` that occur between 10am and 12am between the two dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a **`$project`** step that project the other fields as well as a new field which shows the hour part of the datetime field `time`. Then the next stage should combine the two filters i.e. the coordinates, date and hour ranges into one **`$match`** pipeline step.

**Mongo query**

```
var start = new Date(time1);
var end = new Date(time2);

var aggArray = [
    {
        "$project": {
            "coordinates": "$payload.location.coordinates",
            "datetime": "$time",
            "hour_part": { "$hour": "$time" }
        },
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "coordinates.0": { "$gte": longmin, "$lte": longmax},
            "coordinates.1": { "$gte": latmin, "$lte": latmax},
            "datetime": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end },
            "hour_part": { "$gte": 10, "$lte": 12 }
        }       
    }
];
```

**PHP equivalent**

```
$start = new MongoDate($time1);
$end = new MongoDate($time2);

$aggArray = array(
    array(
        "$project" => array(
            "coordinates" => "payload.location.coordinates",
            "datetime" => "$time",
            "hour_part": array( "$hour" => "$time" )            
        ),
    ),
    array(
        "$match" => array(
            "coordinates.0" => array(
                "$gte" => $longmin,
                "$lte" => $longmax
            ),
            "coordinates.1" => array(
                "$gte" => $latmin,
                "$lte" => $latmax
            ),
            "datetime" => array(
                "$gte" => $start,
                "$lte" => $end
            ),
            "hour_part" => array(
                "$gte" => 10,
                "$lte" => 12
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Is this always the way to approach this problem? I can't off the top of my head think of a situation where you would explicitly require two of the same step (2x $match etc), but should these queries always be changed to some form of single key query?

Comment: In your case it would be wiser to combine the two filters into one `$match` pipeline since it's readable though the final result would still be the same.

Comment: Using this new query ive found it is a lot slower than the first one, im guessing because the aggregation is being carried out on a smaller data set. Is there a way to achieve the same performance?